# I want to sending sata from activity to fragment. but my app is not showing data in frameLayout

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

***This is my MainActivity.java***

***I want to sending sata from activity to fragment. but my app is not showing data in framelayout. I don't know how to do.. please tell me..***

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private EditText mEdittext;
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mEdittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etusername);

    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showFragment();
        }
    });



}

private void showFragment() {


    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    bundle.putString("key","This is aditya sharma");

    mainFragment mainFragment = new mainFragment();

    mainFragment.setArguments(bundle);

    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.frag_container,mainFragment)
            .commit();

}
```

***And this is my mainFragment.java class file***

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();

    if (bundle != null) {

        String message = bundle.getString("Key");
        TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.showtext);

        textView.setText(message);
    }

    return view;
}
```

***and this is my mainactivity.xml file in project***

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/etusername"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="125dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter user name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="154dp" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frag_container"
    android:layout_width="330dp"
    android:layout_height="169dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="243dp"
    android:background="#A7AAB6"></FrameLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="192dp"
    android:text="Show" />
```

***and this is mainfragment.xml file***

```
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/showtext"
 android:textSize="24sp"
 android:text="Hello Blank Fragment"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"></TextView>
```

***and this is logcat***

2020-04-29 12:31:16.990 19483-19483/com.example.testing I/Choreographer: Skipped 2 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

2020-04-29 12:31:20.104 19483-19483/com.example.testing I/Choreographer: Skipped 1 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

2020-04-29 12:31:20.396 19483-19483/com.example.testing I/Choreographer: Skipped 1 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

2020-04-29 12:31:20.797 19483-19483/com.example.testing I/Choreographer: Skipped 1 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

2020-04-29 12:31:21.347 19483-19483/com.example.testing I/Choreographer: Skipped 1 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

2020-04-29 12:31:21.892 19483-19483/com.example.testing I/Choreographer: Skipped 1 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: can i see your method in mainActivity - "showFragment"?and if possible Log of error

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: please edit your question with showFragment() method

Comment: if app crashes please post stacktrace

Comment: I again reupload whole code. please check

Comment: The keys you use while setting the value and fetching the value are different.